# Install py2exe for python 2.7 over pip: this package requires Python 3.3 or later

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, py2exe, pypi

```py
>>> python -c "import sys; print sys.version"
2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

>>> pip --version
pip 1.5.5 from C:\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

>>> pip install py2exe
<mumble grumble..>
RuntimeError: This package requires Python 3.3 or later
```

though official [py2exe download page](http://www.py2exe.org/) says they have exactly what I need:

[image: screenshot]

So how to install py2exe over pip?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is missing from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/), if you click on the `0.6.9` link it brings you to the `0.9.2.0` python 3 package, there seems to be no `0.6.9` package available to download.

Try using `pip install http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/latest/download?source=files`

Comment: Worked for me, I did have to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 which it mentioned in the error message I got:
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: I got the following exception from this - `SSLError: hostname 'sourceforge.net' doesn't match u'*.sourceforge.net'`

Answer (score 32):

There is also a wheel of `py2exe` available for Python 2.x: `py2exe_py2 0.6.9`

You can do: `pip install py2exe_py2`

[Pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe_py2) link.

Comment: works for me .. seems the better solution than the accepted answer

Comment: fails for me, the above cmd produces 'collecting py2exe py2exe-py2' (the underscore becomes hyphen) with the message,   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py2exe-py2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for py2exe-py2

Comment: Works for Python2.7 32 bits for Windows

Comment: For those having issues, make sure you're trying from a 32-bit install of Python. This seemed to be the difference between success or not for me: default environment was choosing 64-bit python and pip and failing to find a compatible version.

Comment: It worked for me too! Thanks. (After being through a lot of trouble until now with py2exe installation!)  *** This should be the answer with the higher upvotes *** (Mine didn't change the situation!). But who says that life is fair? :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Anacona, and I install py2.7 via its environments feature, so previous answers were not helpful to me.

```
--------------------------- Cannot install ---------------------------  
Python version 2.7 required, which was not found in the registry.
```

The following is the command I used, it can install py2exe via command line.

```
pip install https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/py2exe/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.zip
...
Successfully installed py2exe-0.6.9
```

Cause py2exe requires Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0, so before installing, you should download and install it, by convenience, via this [link](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi)

Hope this could be helpful, Thx.

Comment: Was getting the same error via the GUI installer, and after installing VC++ 9 for Python via the provided link, this `pip` command worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You may try using pip3. Or if pip3 is not installed or not found, try: `python3 -m pip install py2exe`.

Source: https://superuser.com/a/942338/315157

Comment: the op needs to install for python 2.7, not python3

Answer (score -2):

you can directly download py2exe for python 2.7 from [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/py2exe/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe?r=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fpy2exe%2Ffiles%2Fpy2exe%2F0.6.9%2F&ts=1470111131&use_mirror=jaist)

Comment: the question states to install via pip