# Py2exe not installing properly

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I am trying to install py2exe for my laptop and when I install it I get Retrying (retry(total =4,...) this continues for 5 times and then crashes. Then it states could not find a version that sastisfies the requirements of py2exe. No matching distributions for found for py2exe.

I have python 2.7. I go to https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/ and downloaded the correct 2.7 version. When i go to do a pip install it wont work. I double click the executable and let it download. a Py2exe folder is created. I moved that folder to the directory C:\Python27\Scripts and run "pip install py2exe"

```
pip install py2exe
```

I expect the results to successfully run the install so I can start creating executable but it wont run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install py2exe for python 2.7 over pip: this package requires Python 3.3 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734172/install-py2exe-for-python-2-7-over-pip-this-package-requires-python-3-3-or-late)

Comment: @CodeIt Hey thank you for that heads up. But that solution did not work either.

Comment: Try `pip install py2exe_py2`. Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31217264/3091398)

Comment: @CodeIt Hey, this did not work either. I dont know what the issue is. It is something simple I am missing perhaps?

Comment: Try this `python2.7 -m pip install https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/py2exe/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.zip`

Comment: @CodeIt thank you very much. this made progress, I saw a download % and saw the following issue now: "Failed Building Wheel for py2exe"

Comment: @CodeIt i fixed this issue but now it keeps timing out

Comment: @CodeIt sorry it submitted before I was finished. It keeps timing out with "Retrying(Retry(Total4,....) and counts down to 0 and says max try attempted. I am using a work laptop, i wonder it if is my proxy settings?

Comment: Download the file `https://nchc.dl.sourceforge.net/project/py2exe/py2exe/0.6.9/py2exe-0.6.9.zip` and copy the path and use it with this command `python2.7 -m pip install py2exe-0.6.9.zip`.

Comment: @CodeIt First of all thank you for being so patient and helpful, it is much appreciated! I am trying my best to debug and not bother you and this should in theory be easy since its an installation but idk. Downloading, fixed that issue but now it is encountering a new issue, distirbuted 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed and grin 1.2.1 requires argparse>=1.1, which is not installed. then moves to one more error can't install py2exe. it is a distutils installed project and thus we cant accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: @CodeIt ok i fixed the msgpack and argparse issue. I dont know if I am having an issue or now but it says successfully built py2exe and then installing collected pacakges: py2exe found existing installation: py2exe 0.6.9, then it says cannot uninstall 'py2exe'. The error is the last sentence above. I dont know if I am done or not?

Comment: You can check if py2exe is installed or not using `python2.7 -m pip show py2exe`.

Comment: @CodeIt Thank you. It appears to be working now.Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Glad that it worked.

Comment: @CodeIt i really appreciate it all. I have another issue now but its a different post i guess. I had openpyxl and wrote codes that worked perfectly fine. But I am assuming with all the changes as a result of this, my openpyxl module is not working anymore. When I run the code it does not recognize it anymore even though the files are in the python folder.